# installing present on ghc-7.10

Tags: dependencies, ghc, cabal

I am trying to install `present` on GHC-7.10.1 (cabal-1.22) on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. But I got an error message about `cabal: Could not resolve dependencies`.

I was wondering if anyone has had success on installing `present`, and can share the experience?

Thanks.

P.S.: the error messages:

```
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
trying: present-2.2 (user goal)
trying: base-4.8.1.0/installed-206... (dependency of present-2.2)
trying: atto-lisp-0.2.2 (dependency of present-2.2)
next goal: deepseq (dependency of atto-lisp-0.2.2)
rejecting: deepseq-1.4.1.1/installed-774..., 1.4.1.1, 1.4.1.0, 1.4.0.0
(conflict: atto-lisp => deepseq>=1.1 && <1.4)
rejecting: deepseq-1.3.0.2 (conflict: base==4.8.1.0/installed-206..., deepseq
=> base>=4.3 && <4.8)
trying: deepseq-1.3.0.1
next goal: array (dependency of deepseq-1.3.0.1)
rejecting: array-0.5.1.0/installed-9bf..., 0.5.1.0, 0.5.0.0 (conflict: deepseq
=> array>=0.1 && <0.5)
rejecting: array-0.4.0.1 (conflict: base==4.8.1.0/installed-206..., array =>
base>=4.2 && <4.7)
rejecting: array-0.4.0.0 (conflict: base==4.8.1.0/installed-206..., array =>
base>=4.2 && <4.6)
rejecting: array-0.3.0.3 (conflict: base==4.8.1.0/installed-206..., array =>
base>=4.2 && <4.5)
rejecting: array-0.3.0.2, 0.3.0.1 (conflict: base==4.8.1.0/installed-206...,
array => base>=4.2 && <4.4)
rejecting: array-0.3.0.0 (conflict: base==4.8.1.0/installed-206..., array =>
base>=3 && <4.4)
rejecting: array-0.2.0.0, 0.1.0.0 (conflict: base==4.8.1.0/installed-206...,
array => base<4.3)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
```

Comment: You might have luck with `cabal install --allow-newer`. Upon closer inspection though, it looks like the problem is atto-lisp specifying deepseq>=1.1 && < 1.4. This is a problem because it appears deepseq 1.4.1.1 allows installing with base 4.8.1.0 (your version).

If the deepseq API didn't change, this should work and atto-lisp's bounds should be relaxed to include deepseq-1.4.1.1:

cabal install --constraint="deepseq==1.4.1.1"